# SQL increment a number

Tags: sql, t-sql

Problem:

I want to increment a number based on a table.
So for example, if a table contains 
row

```
1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5
```

mytable column should increment based on this taking the max(row) + 1 in the above column. So the outcome should look like this:

```
6 6 7 8 9 9 9 10
```

This is the code so far:

```
OPEN cur

DECLARE @WORKING_ON_ID INT
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @WORKING_ON_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
                SET @MAX_ID = @MAX_ID + 1

                UPDATE 
                                #WorkingTable
                SET
                                ID = @MAX_ID
                WHERE
                                ID = @WORKING_ON_ID

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @WORKING_ON_ID

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Could you please help me in getting a solution to this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you could do it easily with this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET id = id + (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table)
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be easier to just take the maximum and add it to this ID column? (Remember: the **ID column can't be an identity column**, otherwise an update will fail)

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT
SELECT @MAXID = MAX(ID) FROM #WorkingTable
UPDATE #WorkingTable SET ID = ID + @MAXID
```

Comment: It is not picking the maximum id...177-- original 178-- original  178 -- original 179 -- original 356 357 357 358

Comment: I is somehow adding the max and the ID...to produce 356

Comment: @user1047883 thats exaclty what the query does.

Comment: Matten, I have the same comment... so I'm quite sure that I was not the only one to understand which query was needed... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Marco - somehow the author was confused what our queries do, but it looks like if the problem solved itself.

Answer (score 4):

Please Try this Code:

```
Declare @count int = 0
UPDATE table
SET @count = code = @count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a cursor? Wouldn't this solve your problem as well:

```
DECLARE @MAXID int
SELECT @MAXID=MAX(ID) FROM YourTable
UPDATE YourTable SET ID = ID + @MAXID
```

Comment: "Why use a cursor?" is right. On a side note, always try to solve your problem without cursors first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works better without the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005 or later version:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, MAX(ID) OVER () AS delta FROM atable
)
UPDATE cte
SET ID = ID + delta;
```