# update order column in a table but maintain the order

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

i have a table

```
id | title | F_ID  | order
----------------------------
1  | test 1| 1     | 44
2  | test 3| 1     | 3
3  | test 4| 1     | 1
4  | test 5| 2     | 1
```

i want to update order column to +10 for all rows that have F_ID 1 but keep the order

the result need to be

```
id | title | F_ID  | order
----------------------------
1  | test 1| 1     | 30
2  | test 3| 1     | 20
3  | test 4| 1     | 10
4  | test 5| 2     | 1
```

i can insert all rows that i want to update to temp table
and then loop the rows and update every row in the real table by [id].

maybe there is a better option?

Comment: This sort of thing would probably work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401552/sql-increment-a-number  The trick seems to be SET x = X + 10

Comment: no, i need to give a all new number not increase it

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. If your adding +10 to order,w hen F_ID =1. In your example, first column went down by 14, 2nd went up by 17, and third went up by 9.

Comment: i want gust to "pretty" my order and make "space" for new items. the change of the number is by x so "new order" start from x and increase by y, but the order is equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4688/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (id int, title  varchar(49), F_ID int, [order] int)
insert test values 
(1  , 'test 1', 1, 44),
(2  , 'test 3', 1, 3),
(3  , 'test 4', 1, 1),
(4  , 'test 5', 2, 1)
```

**Query 1**:

```
update test
set [order] = new_order
from test t
inner join (
    select 
       id, 
       new_order = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by f_id order by [order]) * 10
    from test t
    where f_id = 1
) t2 
on t.id = t2.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4688/2/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select * from test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4688/2/1)**:

```
| ID |  TITLE | F_ID | ORDER |
|----|--------|------|-------|
|  1 | test 1 |    1 |    30 |
|  2 | test 3 |    1 |    20 |
|  3 | test 4 |    1 |    10 |
|  4 | test 5 |    2 |     1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be a better solution then this but you can try this by using recursive CTE.

```
;WITH updCTE
AS 
(
    SELECT 30 AS YourOrder, 1 AS id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT YourOrder - 10 AS YourOrder, id + 1 AS id
    FROM updCTE
    WHERE YourOrder > 1
)
UPDATE YourTable
SET [order] = YourOrder
FROM updCTE
JOIN YourTable ON updCTE.id = YourTable.id
WHERE YourTable.F_ID = 1
ORDER BY YourTable.id
```

Comment: my id is not start from 1 and increase by 1, it could be any number